# Append value to document.getElementByID("div");

Tags: javascript

I am looking to create multiple charts via chart.js with a for-loop. I am using PHP Framework Laravel to load the data and the data is inside each element but I am having one problem appending the number of each element to the canvas ID

The chart is being drawn within a canvas tag

```
<canvas 
   id="piechart{{ $article->id }}"
   value=" {{ $article->id }}"
   data-id="{{ $article->id }}"
   data .... 
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
var chart = document.getElementsById("piechart");
// chart stuff
```

Basically, I need to select "piechart" + n for each associated chart. How can I call getDocumentById and append a value or data-id ?

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get an array of elements which match a CSS selector.

Then when you have the charts, you can use the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property to get and set data on each of the charts.

```
var charts = document.querySelectorAll("canvas[id^=piechart]");

charts.forEach(function (chart) {
  // get a value with dataset.value. NOTE: data-id="x" maps to dataset.id
  var id = chart.dataset.id;

  // set some data
  chart.dataset.name = "Chart with ID " + id;

  // chart is the DOM element, so has all the usual properties, e.g. 
  chart.width = 100;
  chart.height = 100;
});
```

---

**Side note:**

It's probably worth considering adding a class to the piecharts so that they can be selected and styled as a group, but targeted directly via their ID as required for your charting library.

```
<canvas 
    id="piechart{{ $article->id }}"
    value=" {{ $article->id }}"
    data-id="{{ $article->id }}"
    class="piechart">
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var charts = document.querySelectorAll(".piechart");

    charts.forEach(function (chart) {
        // snip
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery:

```
var charts = $('div[id^="piechart"]');
```

If you want to use native JavaScript:

```
var charts = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="piechart"]');
```

now, you have an array of your `div` which their `id` begin with `piechart`